# Xcode clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, xcode, segmentation-fault

I got this error on Xcode, after updating my buddy's code from svn and building it.

> clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
>
> clang: error: linker command failed due to signal

The changes were only on 2 class's implementation files. I tried reverting the code using `svn up`, cleaning and rebuilding it. (Heck, I even tried restarting Xcode, still I was getting the same issue.) But the next day the updated version was working fine. And I have no clue of what happened!

I want to know why this error occurred and how did it vanish after a system restart?

Answer (score 2):

No Sure about your particular error. But mine was due to two external library was conflicting. Its less xcode error but more command line error in build tool chain. I would suggest to remove external libraries one by one and see what is causing the issue. 
In my case once I removed culprit library. It built fine. good luck